# Softening a TextView edges

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

I need to add a scrollable android TextView, which will show alot of text.

I want to achieve this kind of effect:

[image: Soft edge textbox]

But I found no way of doing so.

Is there any good way of doing it?

Thank you!

Comment: put an ImageView in front of a TextVIew, and put a gradient picture in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below properties to TextView

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
android:fadingEdgeLength="32dp" //To change the gradient overlay height
```

Comment: You are Welcome...!

Answer (score 0):

The most convient way of doing this is creating a drawable. You can either make your own image in the image editing software of your choice or create a [GradientDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html). Make sure the colors go from white to transparent. Then place this drawable on top of the textview near the bottom.